# Apache virtual host redirect for wordpress on localhost:8000 via www.example.com

Tags: apache, localhost, port, virtualhost

I'm moving 2 wordpress websites (one of them is a subdomain) to my local machine under docker containers for development.

I would like to access them in my development machine by their domain names using the hosts file, but I'm struggling to get my apache virtual hosts to work.

Let's say:
Site 1 is 'www.example.com'
Site 2 is 'sub.example.com'
Each have their own MySQL database and wordpress code base, setup on different docker-compose containers.

So:
Site 1: wwww.example.com on http://localhost:8000
Site 2: sub.example.com on http://localhost:8001
both work fine via localhost:8000 and localhost:8001

I altered my local hosts file to have:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost  
127.0.0.1       example.com www.example.com sub.example.com
```

I'm struggling to setup the apache virtual hosts for this situation,
this is what I've tried:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ProxyPass /  http://localhost:8000/
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub.example.com
    ProxyPass /  http://localhost:8001/
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
```

Going directly to http://localhost:8000 and http://localhost:8001 works.

When I go to http://www.example.com I get the following error:

> **Service Unavailable**
>   The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
>   Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) Server at www.example.com Port 80

and on http://sub.example.com:

> **Service Unavailable**
>   The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
>   Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) Server at sub.example.com Port 80

**Can someone point me in the right direction on how to setup the virtual hosts please?**

Thank you

Comment: The problem is deeper than I originally thought, I forgot to mention that apache is running in its own docker container. To solve the problem will involve knowledge of docker exposed ports, apache virtual hosts, hosts file, and correct wordpress settings e.g. table wp_options: home and siteurl. 
Would a re-worded question still be off-topic here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I understand that my question may be off-topic here, but since I managed to solve my problem, I hope you will allow my answer to remain here so that it may help someone else.**

I failed to mention that the apache server was running in its own Docker container.

This is what I did to solve the problem:

### In the host machine:

Include www.example.com, example.com and sub.example.com in the hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost  
127.0.0.1       example.com www.example.com sub.example.com
```

### In the apache docker container:

Since apache is running in its own docker container, localhost:8000 points to apache docker container's localhost which is incorrect here.
It needs to point to the host machine's ip address, which in my case is 192.168.1.100.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ProxyPass /  http://192.168.1.100:8000/
    ProxyPassReverse /  http://192.168.1.100:8000/
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub.example.com
    ProxyPass /  http://192.168.1.100:8001/
    ProxyPassReverse /  http://192.168.1.100:8001/
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
```

Restart apache

### On each Worpdress Site:

The last thing to do is to change the 'site_url' and 'home' settings to point to the host machine's ip address (192.168.1.100 here).
This can be done by 2 ways:
Either by going to the wordpress database, table wp_options and modifying:
**site_url** and **home** to *http://192.168.1.100:8000* for www.example.com and example.com; and
**site_url** and **home** to *http://192.168.1.100:8001* for sub.example.com

Or by logging into your Wordpress Dashboard (/wp-admin) then going to *Settings* and modifying:
**WordPress Address (URL)** and **Site Address (URL)** to *http://192.168.1.100:8000* for www.example.com and example.com; and
**WordPress Address (URL)** and **Site Address (URL)** to *http://192.168.1.100:8001* for sub.example.com

You shouldn't need to restart the Wordpress containers, but if you get any errors, restart them and check again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try checking the logs located in `var/log/httpd`(You can also try `sudo locate access.log`) for the actual error that is happening.

The one thing you are missing is `ProxyPassReverse` which will rewrite the URL if your website is redirecting. With it your configuration will look something like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ProxyPass /  http://localhost:8000/
    ProxyPassReverse /  http://localhost:8000/
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub.example.com
    ProxyPass /  http://localhost:8001/
    ProxyPassReverse /  http://localhost:8001/
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I added the ProxyPassReverse, restarted apache, same error, checked the logs and realised that my apache is in a docker container also, so localhost defines the apache docker localhost and not the host machine's localhost... I changed localhost:8001 to host_machine_ip:8001 then it seemed to work. I need to do more tests as a new issue has appeared,,, thank you for the help.